# Baseurl not applying to jekyll posts.

Tags: jekyll

All pages are working correctly with baseurl except my posts.

What I'm  getting
url
https://pizzapgh.github.io/general/2016/08/29/example-post-three/

What I need isntead, "/katietest" before general
https://pizzapgh.github.io/katietest/general/2016/08/29/example-post-three/

In my config I have:
baseurl: /katietest
url "http://pizzapgh.github.io"

Repo
https://github.com/pizzapgh/katietest

Suggestions? I've worked with this before and all I had to do was set the baseurl. I can't seem find out what it is that's not making my post not show.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `_includes/post_list.hmtl` you can replace two occurrences of :

```
<h5><a href="{{ page.url }}"...
```

by

```
<h5><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}"...
```

And you can do the same in `_includes/post_list.hmtl`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I understand what happened now.